# How to list the GCP project which are not part of any folders

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to compose a code which will first look for the project list in my organization which are not under any folder and then run the describe option to filter out the creation date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

what you're looking for is this:
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v3/projects/list

By searching through GCloud docs on [how to create folders](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-folders#gcloud), I was able to find the `gcloud` tab (which corresponds to the python tool in the Cloud Shell) and found the `resource-manager` option, from there I went over to [the documentation for the REST API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest) and from there I looked under `projects` to find a way to list them. By default the REST API only calls direct descendants, so the folders are ignored[^1].

I would recommend taking a look at [the guide for making questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it might make it easier for you to get an answer to your qeustion sooner.

---

[^1] So, if you call it via the organization, you'll get a list of only the projects that are directly under the organization and all folders inside are ignored. You can do the same for folders, by calling it via a folder you'll only get the projects in that folder that are not inside any other folder.